# Information about Spice and Wolf Manga

Tags: spice-and-wolf

So I completed the Spice and Wolf anime, seasons yesterday. And found the ending unsatisfying, so incomplete.

Now I want to complete the story, so I tried looking for the manga on some websites online but I could only find the manga up till Volume 6, which is part of season 1 of the anime.

I did find out that the light novel is way ahead with 15 volumes (anime completed at 5th excluding 4th volume) but I don't like reading light novels.

Later I did find  [something on amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Ddigital-text&field-keywords=spice+and+wolf+manga&rh=n%3A133140011%2Ck%3Aspice+and+wolf+manga)
It claims its volume 13th of the manga, but I am not sure it really is.

Now I want to buy the manga, but where can I buy them? And does the manga really extend beyond the 6th volume I already managed to find?

Comment: I rephrased your question quite a bit. If anything is lost, feel free to add it back in again. Also we do not endorse promoting illegal providers (like the site you linked) so try to refrain from using them in the future

Comment: cool you made my question way much better and understandable thanks @Dimitrimx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the Spice and Wolf anime follow the same events as the manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5495/does-the-spice-and-wolf-anime-follow-the-same-events-as-the-manga)

Comment: @AkiTanaka no it isnt i read the whole thread before making my own plus it does not answer my question.....

Comment: @AyushKatoch From the original question, I think you want to know how many manga volumes the anime cover, which I have posted a new answer there.

Comment: You answered that question few minutes ago so i didnt bothered looking again (when you made that duplicate comment) now its there and yes answered my question too thanks. @AkiTanaka

Comment: ...how much searching did you do? Literally thirty seconds of searching 'Spice and wolf manga' on Amazon turned up all 13 volumes of the manga. If you're not in the US, then it would help to mention that in your question, as the answer to 'where can I find this?' may be different for different countries.

Answer (score 3):

> And does the manga really extend beyond the 6th volume I already managed to find?

yes. according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spice_and_Wolf) in the Manga part of the Info Box

> Manga
>   Written by: Isuna Hasekura
>   Illustrated by: Keito Koume
>   Published by:   ASCII Media Works
>   English publisher:  
>    - NA: Yen Press
>   Demographic:    Seinen
>   Magazine:   Dengeki Maoh
>   Original run:   September 27, 2007 – December 27, 2017
>   **Volumes:  16**

and while incomplete (as of 12/01/2018) [the list of Manga Chapters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Spice_and_Wolf_chapters) shows 15 volumes. you can also see a list of volumes and where you can buy them on [Yen Press's Website](http://www.b2c.hachettebookgroup.com/series/spice-and-wolf-manga/?yen) (if you are looking for the English release)